# Swift overriding + with multiple types and long expressions

Tags: regex, swift

I am trying to make a convenience class for building complex regular expressions in swift. This part works as intended:

```
/**
A RegexAtom contains a regular expression pattern, or fragment of a pattern. Capture groups can be named with the groupNames array.
RegexAtom does no syntax checking on the pattern. Typical usage is to define several fragments of a regex pattern, and then combine
them using finalPattern = foo + bar + soom
*/
public class RegexAtom{
    var regex: String = ""
    var groupNames: [String] = []
    public init(regex: String, groupNames:[String]){
        self.regex = regex
        self.groupNames = groupNames
    }
    public init(regex: String){
        self.regex = regex
        self.groupNames = []
    }

}
func +(left: RegexAtom, right: RegexAtom) -> RegexAtom{
    var foo = RegexAtom(regex: left.regex,groupNames: left.groupNames)
    foo.regex += right.regex
    foo.groupNames.extend(right.groupNames)
    return foo
}
```

I can add complex RegexAtoms using the + , and it complies and runs just fine.

The problem comes from wanting to be able to handle literal strings a bit more compactly, as is done in PyParsing (I miss PyParsing :( )

this function kind of works:

```
func +(left:RegexAtom, right: String)->RegexAtom{
var foo = RegexAtom(regex: left.regex,groupNames: left.groupNames)
foo.regex.extend(right)
return foo
```

}

but if I try to build up a complex regex like this

```
let WS: RegexAtom = RegexAtom(regex:"\\s*")
let tableHeader1 = RegexAtom(regex: "Date") + WS + "Flight" + WS + "Depart" + WS + "Arrive" + WS + "Eq" + WS + "Blk" + WS + "Grnd" + WS + "Blk" + WS + "Duty" + WS + "Cred"
```

I get a compile error:

"Expression was too complex to be solved in a reasonable time. Consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions."

But this works fine:

```
let tableHeader1 = RegexAtom(regex: "Date") + WS + "Flight"
```

The longer expression doesn't seem ridiculously long to me, but I have minimal experience in Xcode or swift.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wow Thanks for two great and quick answers. I was really spoiled for choice to pick one. Looks like I was trying to run a mile to save a step, I'll just deal with the extra verbosity until my knowledge catches up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things here that are combining together to cause your problem.

Firstly, this kind of thing is best avoided:

```
func +(left: RegexAtom, right: String) -> RegexAtom { ... }
```

for two reasons. This kind of silent type coercion is a bit frowned-upon in Swift.  For example, there is no standard library operator that allows you to add an integer to a float.  And people tend to assume `+` is commutative (i.e. a + b == b + a), so you'd need to define a version where left is a string and right is a regex.

The second issue is that `"thing"` is *not* a `String`.  It's a string literal, which can create any type that implements `StringLiteralConvertible`.  The default type is a `String`, but it could also be a `Character` or a `StaticString` or any other custom type.

Swift's type inference engine is pretty accommodating – it will try hard to find a possible match for all the types you've thrown into an expression. And then if there are multiple matches, it'll try to pick the best one based on a bunch of precedence rules.  But in the big expression, there's just too many possibilities, and investigating them all is a combinatoric nightmare, so it just gives up.

Think about your simple example.  The interpretation Swift is picking is this:

```
let tableHeader1 = (RegexAtom(regex: "Date") + WS) + ("Flight" as String)
```

This is because + is left associative and string literals default to `String`.  But it also had to consider some other alternatives:

```
// this will have been considered and rejected, because there's no operator
// that adds characters to regexes
let tableHeader1 = (RegexAtom(regex: "Date") + WS) + ("Flight" as Character)

// this will compile, but the other version is preferred because + is left-
// associative.  But if the first version resulted in an expression that
// didn't compile (say a regex plus a regex equals an integer), it would
// fall back to this possibility
let tableHeader1 = RegexAtom(regex: "Date") + (WS + ("Flight" as String))
```

Now, imagine the combinatorial explosion of possibilities that your extra-long expression of plusses implies.

As an alternative, you could consider ditching the `+(RegexAtom,String)` operator, and instead making `RegexAtom` conform to `StringLiteralConvertible`:

```
extension RegexAtom: StringLiteralConvertible {
    public init(stringLiteral: String) {
        self.init(regex: stringLiteral)
    }
    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral: String) {
        self.init(regex: extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral)
    }
    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral: String) {
        self.init(regex: unicodeScalarLiteral)
    }
}
```

If you do this, it looks like your complex expression will compile OK.

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, this is more of a Swift bug than anything of your doing. If you can roll it up into a minimal example to attach to a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) I'm sure it'd help Apple sort out cases like this.

Meanwhile, it's probably better to use the [`join`](http://swiftdoc.org/func/join/) function for cases like this anyway. If you had a bunch of strings you wanted to concat with the same separator, you'd write something like:

```
join(" and ", ["lions", "tigers", "bears"]) 
// returns "lions and tigers and bears", oh my!
```

If you can make your `RegexAtom` type comply with the [`ExtensibleCollectionType`](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/ExtensibleCollectionType) and [`StringLiteralConvertible`](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/StringLiteralConvertible/) protocols, you'll be able to write something like:

```
let WS: RegexAtom = RegexAtom(regex:"\\s*")
let tableHeader1 = join(WS, ["Date", "Flight", /*etc*/ ] as [RegexAtom])
```

The `as` trick above is one way to get the compiler to type-infer an array of string literals as an array of `RegexAtom`. Here are a couple more:

```
let a: [RegexAtom] = ["a", "b"] // infer via type declaration
let b = [RegexAtom](["a", "b"]) // infer via array constructor
let c = [RegexAtom("a"), "b"] // infer from first element
```

---

What's presumably going on here is that every `+` operator in that long expression adds depth to the type-checking process. For example consider the expression `a + b + c + d`: in order to perform type inference and select the right `+` functions to use, the compiler has to look everything in the expression and  decide whether it looks like this:

```
+ ——— + ——— String
 \     \——— String
  \—— + ——— String
       \——— String
```

Or like this:

```
+ ——— + ——— RegExAtom
 \     \——— RegExAtom
  \—— + ——— RegExAtom
       \——— RegExAtom
```

Or like some other variation involving any number of other types (arrays, numbers) or values whose type is indeterminate (like literals, whose type is decided by the expression they're used in via protocols like `StringLiteralConvertible`). There are a lot of possible types and conversions available just for one `a + b` operation, and every time you chain another operator you exponentially increase the complexity of type checking.

Nobody wants the compiler to hang indefinitely while trying to evaluate an expression, so if the type-checking operation starts taking too long, it just gives up. There are probably ways Apple can improve the efficiency here so that operations that are linguistically legal can be practically supported, so [file bugs](http://bugreport.apple.com) and you can help them catch the ugly performance cases.

(If you want to better understand the theory going into things like this, read [some books with dragons on the covers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_construction).)